# Confusion about maven, osgi and eclipse

Tags: java, maven, osgi

I have been dealing with maven and osgi for a few weeks time now and still get confused regarding dependencies and bundles/packages/plug-ins. Mainly i cant understand what they are. Because im new to both java and osgi/maven its hard for me to visualize how they are connected or what is a part of the other. So not to be too vague ill try to ask a bunch of specific questions.

1) As i understand bundles and plug-ins are same things - just different name. Is package also the same thing? I found many debates on the topic "should i use import-package or require-bundle" but i cant really understand them before i understand what a package or bundle is.

2) Dependencys. For example if i want to use slf4j api i add this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

But what does that really mean? I understand that adding the dependency will make the usage of slf4j available to me. Can i assume that the "thing" im depending on is just a compiled project (like the one i make locally) somewhere in maven repository?

3) Osgi bundles. If my previous notion is correct (dependencys are like projects) then are bundles like packages under project? If so then i assume that one dependency may add the possibility of adding multiple osgi plugins. If so then where can i see what dependency makes what imports available. Im asking this because i noticed that the name i write under import-package isnt always the same in the dependency.

4) When launching osgi configuration in eclipse i have to select plug-ins. There are some i can select from under target platform and as i understand i have to select all the plugins i imported in manifest. What is this target platform and where did those plugins get there?

These are long (and probably really stupid questions) so i really appreciate any help. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing to remember is that Maven and OSGi have completely different roles:

Maven is a build tool. It is responsible for compiling your code (using the javac compiler) and assembling the result into bundles (jar files) on the disk... and that's it. Maven doesn't *run* your code.

OSGi is a runtime modularity framework. It takes bundle files that have been built by Maven or any other build system, and creates a framework for them to run in. OSGi doesn't tell you how to build the bundles, but it does place some constraints on their contents that have to be satisfied by whatever build tool you use.

Now to answer your specific questions:

1. A "plug-in" is Eclipse terminology for a bundle. This arose because Eclipse used a different module system than OSGi prior to version 3. Now they are the same thing. A package is NOT the same thing, it is a Java package as in the package declaration that you put at the top of your Java source files. Typically a bundle will contain one or more packages.
2. A dependency in the Maven `pom.xml` means that the specified jar file will be made visible to the javac compiler when it compiles your code. Remember that Maven is a build tool so this only specifies a build-time dependency. This is required because if you use a symbol in your Java source such as `org.slf4j.Logger` then the javac compiler has to find that symbol on the classpath. Otherwise the compilation of your code will fail.
3. OSGi bundles are the output of your build process, and the physical modules loaded by the runtime OSGi framework. Essentially a bundle is just a jar file with some OSGi-specific entries in its `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`. Because it is a file you can save it, move it around, deploy it into an application etc. OSGi loads this file and creates a runtime module that encapsulates the contents of the bundle. A whole application is typically made out of many bundles.
4. To run an OSGi application you have to tell OSGi which bundles to include. From the combination of bundles that you choose, an application emerges. The target platform is a kind of repository of bundles that have been built, and it includes both the bundles that you write yourself plus the third party bundles, e.g. libraries like slf4j and so on. The contents of the target platform are configured using the preferences dialog in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you learn each separately first. You can use Maven and OSGi independently. OSGi has multiple implementations and Equinox is one which is from Eclipse.

1 - OSGi has bundles, Eclipse calls them plug-ins so yes same thing. A package is a java pacakge.

2 - Dependencies are a maven concept. You can read here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

3 - A bundle is an OSGi artifact. It is basically a jar file with a speical manifest.

4 - On launch you need to tell OSGi which jar files you want to load. The speical manifest has directives that tell OSGi how to initialize your app.

Hope that helps.